# how to send a url with facebook like button?

Tags: facebook-like

I have page which has the url like the following.

```
http://example.com/?f=chatter
```

It has three links.
When I click on a link it details page is display. Which has the url like

```
http://example.com/?f=chatter&aid=6
```

But this url does not appear in the browser address bar. It displays in a textbox on its details page. The url in address bar remains the same `http://example.com/?f=chatter`

My page is of .tpl

Now I want to add the facebook like button to the details page which will share the link of that details page which is displaying in the textbox.

But when I click on the facebook like button, it share the link which is in the address bar of the browser.

```
{$url} this contains the details page url which is displaying in the textbox.
```

I have used the following code of the facebook like button.

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href={$url};send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Where in href I have place the `{$url}`.

Comment: Be sure to URL encode your $url.

Comment: yes, with url encode it solved my problem. But Now how can I do this with tweet button?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be useful to you but I'm using a jquery plugin that is unfortunatly not free ($5) called [jQuery Social Share Buttons plugin](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/premium-jquery-plugins/jquery-social-share-buttons-plugin-example-2/)

Although I'm having problems getting the facebook like button to include a popup which allows posting the url to my feed (keep getting 'Unknown RPC service: widget-interactive' error when trying to implement), I was able to get the twitter button to post the url.